# Unable to build with an old kernel branch. Seems to take the most recent one each time

Tags: linux, makefile, build, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm under Mint.
I want to build ufs kernel module for the kernel "4.15.0-54-generic" (to add write support).
Here my version :

```
~$ uname -a
> Linux user-virtual-machine 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can't make my module with the current running kernel version.

I tried different things without results :

```
sudo apt source linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic
~$ make kernelversion
> 4.15.18
```

I tried with git repo with the exact same results:

```
~$ git clone --depth 1 --branch Ubuntu-4.15.0-54.58 git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic
~$ cd bionic
~$ make kernelversion
> 4.15.18
```

I built the kernel module ufs (by compiling with `make modules`) and it gives me this :

```
$ modinfo ufs.ko
filename:       /home/user/my_dir/ufs.ko
license:        GPL
alias:          fs-ufs
srcversion:     42FF006F08C1903C2AA3E49
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ufs
vermagic:       4.15.18 SMP mod_unload
```

So the command fails:

```
ufs: version magic '4.15.18 SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.15.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

Can you please tell me what did I do wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Name of the directory with the Linux kernel doesn't affect on the version of the kernel. It is just a convenience that a directory has the same name as the version (`uname -r`).

Comment: Yes but I have clearly "linux (4.15.0-54.58) bionic" in my "debian.master/changelog" file. So how come the module came out in 4.15.18 ?
I changed my question to understand more easely my issue.